# Because of the green screen, my computer went back in time two years

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, windows-11

Today I got a green screen of death. after a minute or so the computer restated itself and it chenged from windows 11 with all my files and programs to **windows 10 with files and programs that I created 2 years ago**.

and now every time I open the computer it shows me A LOT of errors from application like discord ext

I tried to install aiseesoft data recovery application but the files that its giving me are in wierd formats like xml and rtf so its not helping that much

Can someone try and help me find a way to recover back to windows 11 with my programs & files?

Comment: When was your last backup?

Comment: Something is quite odd that it should simply "go back". I think that it's likely that you had the Windows 10 all along as a 2nd boot option or 2nd disk. Can you check Disk Management to see what it gives you?

Comment: Were you on the Windows 11 Insider program?  That may have caused this.

Comment: @John, he's obviously on the insider program, given the GSOD instead of BSOD. The question is, though, how the system flew back to an old OS.

Comment: I am not sure how it went back automatically, but I have Insider instances of Keep Nothing and reverting to a prior point but I had to force one of my machines back to Windows 10 . It was not automatic